# sagemaker transform not filtering input as expeced

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Am trying to batch transform a csv file using this code

**Processor script**

```
text_preparation_model = SKLearnModel(
    sagemaker_session = local_session,
    entry_point='processor.py',
    role=context.role,
    framework_version=..,
    image_uri=...,
    model_data=...)
```

**processor.py**

```
def input_fn(input_data, content_type):
    if content_type == 'text/csv':
        df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(input_data), names=['feature_col1'],quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, escapechar='\\')
        print(df.head())

        return df
    else:
        raise ValueError("{} .Error ".format(content_type))
```

**Transform**

```
text_preparation_transformer.transform(
    'file://validation.txt',  
    content_type='text/csv',
    split_type='Line',
    logs=context.show_logs,
    input_filter='$[0]',
    join_source='Input'
)
```

the file is 2 columns separated with comma and values are enclosed in double quotes `ex` "some feature value","label_1".
[image]
in refernce to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/batch-transform-data-processing.html),
I expected to receive only the feature column in the `processor script`, but I keep getting both columns

Answer (score 0):

input_filter='$[0]' will only include the column from the input. What could be creating trouble for you is the `input_fn` implementation, can you confirm the output of `df` to see it has "column" based comma [separated](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/sagemaker_batch_transform/batch_transform_associate_predictions_with_input) values.
An example for using joining filters can be found here

Comment: it seems something related to being run locally or on cloud, as the code turned to work fine on cloud